# unknown type for collapse field `xxx`, only keywords and numbers are accepted error

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

If I add a collapse clause to the following query the error

> "unknown type for collapse `aircraft_type_search`, only keywords
>   and numbers are accepted"

is returned.

```
 {
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {
              "aircraft_type_search": {
                "query": "piper"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "bool": {
        "must": {
          "term": {
            "display_picture": "yes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"collapse": {
  "field": "aircraft_type_search"
}
}
```

I have also tried `'aircraft_id'` as the collapse field as that is an integer:

```
'aircraft_id' => [ 'type' => 'integer', "null_value" => "-1", "ignore_malformed" => 'true', 'include_in_all' => 'false', 'index' => 'not_analyzed' ]
```

but that resulted in the error.

ES7.1 on AWS Elastic Search service running through the elasticsearch php sdk.

If I remove the collapse clause the query works fine.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because collapse is only for keyword and numbers fields as the error says.

You have two sollutions :

1. Provide a keyword mapping of your field at the index creation

```
    PUT my-index
    {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "aircraft_type_search" : {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

2. Use the Elastic default mapping that include text and keyword and call the keyword on the query 
   :

```
    "collapse": {
        "field": "aircraft_type_search.keyword"
      }
```

In order to pick the best solution, you must understand what is a text or a keyword type. If you don't want to deepen the subject, the easiest way is sollution 2.

Comment: I had checked for that and both fields were either number (integer) or keyword type but it still didn't work.   I think the issue stemmed from having other settings for the keyword mapping:

`'type'             => 'keyword', "null_value"       => "-1", "ignore_malformed" => 'true', 'include_in_all'   => 'false', 'index'            => 'not_analyzed',`

If I have a mapping of just `'type' => 'keyword'` then it does work.  I've set up a keyword mapping now and all seems well.  The installation is upgraded from ES1.5 so there's quite a bit of legacy code in there which might not apply to ES7.1